# Get list of parallel paths in a directed graph

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, directed-graph

I'm in need of an algorithm to find sets of all parallel paths in a directed graph. Here is a visual representation of an example I use for testing.

[image: visual representation of example directed graph with a set of parallel paths]

Here is my example code in Python using networkx:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
# relevant part of graph to my question
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(2,5),(5,6),(6,4),(4,7)])
# subordinate part of graph to my question
G.add_edges_from([(7,8),(8,9),(7,10),(10,11),(11,13),(11,12),(12,14)])

pp = get_parallel_paths(G)  # -> the function I'm looking for

# pp should contain:
# pp = [[[(2,3),(3,4)],[(2,5),(5,6),(6,4)]],[...]]
# the procedure should list all sets of parallel paths
# hence the [...] indicates a possible other set of parallel paths (not in example)
```

It is the function "get_parallel_paths" I am looking for. It does not have to be in Python: a pointer to any algorithm that could help me with the implementation is very welcome.

Comment: I have changed my question: it are the parallel paths (each a succession of one or more edges) I am looking for.

Comment: Further clarification: If, in your example, `9` and `14` were the same vertex, then would `[7,10,11,12,9]` and `[7,8,9]` be considered "parallel"? That is, do offshoots interrupt your parallel definition?

Comment: @Kittsil Consider offshoots not possible, hence if 9 and 14 would be the same node, then the paths you are mentioning are not considered parallel paths. By the way: the discipline is electricity networks, and parallel paths are added to increase power capacity over a segment of the network. Offshoots are not supposed to happen on those parallel paths.

Comment: Does the word "parallel" mean anything here, or are you just looking for the set of paths between two vertices?

Comment: @Kundor I do not use "parallel" in the mathematical sense, if that is what you are referring to. In fact, I use "parallel" like [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/classes.multidigraph.html#multidigraph-directed-graphs-with-self-loops-and-parallel-edges) but in stead of edges, my case has paths (succession of edges).

Comment: So for each pair of vertices u and v, you want a list of all the paths from u to v. The word "parallel" isn't usually used here.

Comment: @Kundor Yes, but he then wants to filter the paths so that they only contain simple (non-branching) vertices. That's where the notion of "parallel" comes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a built-in function to list all simple paths between two vertices. This uses it to list all sets of paths between any two vertices:

```
def get_parallel_paths(G):
    return [list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, i, j)) for i in G.nodes_iter() for j in G.nodes_iter() if i != j and nx.has_path(G, i, j)]
```

To filter out any paths with internal vertices of degree greater than two, we can do something like this:

```
def get_parallel_paths(G):
    colpaths = []
    for i in G.nodes_iter():
        for j in G.nodes_iter():
            if i == j:
                continue
            nbp = nobranchpaths(G, i, j)
            if len(nbp) > 1:
                colpaths += [nbp]
    return colpaths

def nobranchpaths(G, u, v):
    paths = []
    for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, u, v):
        if len(p) == 2 or max(G.degree(i) for i in p[1:-1]) == 2:
            paths += [p]
    return paths
```

This only includes pairs of vertices where more than one path exists; to include pairs with a unique path, change `if len(nbp) > 1:` to just `if len(nbp):`

Comment: This could be part of the solution indeed. Like Kittsil wrote in his last comment in the original question: I will have to filter the output to contain only the paths that are distinct branches between two vertices (2 and 4 in the example). I will look into that as well.

Comment: To just get paths between two given vertices, use `nx.all_simple_paths(G, 2, 4)`. To enforce that all internal vertices have degree two, if that's what you want, you'll need an approach like Kittsil's I think; no built-in functions have such constraints.

Comment: @theej or now that I think of it, it's easy enough to just filter out any paths with internal branching vertices. I updated my answer.

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If parallel paths with branches are considered, then this problem would be NP-complete (see [vertex-disjoint paths problem](http://assert-false.net/callcc/Guyslain/Works/disjoint_paths)).

However, since offshoots are not considered, the problem is straightforward:

1. Loop over all vertices.
2. If a vertex has multiple outgoing edges, follow them until they converge.
3. If they converge to the same node, they are parallel paths.

Psuedocode:

```
allParallelPaths = []

#loop over all vertices to find ones that split
foreach(vertices as v)
  if(out-degree(v) > 1) 

    #store every eventual target and the paths that got there
    destinations = new Map()
    foreach(v.out as e)
      path = [e]

      #stop at any vertex that has non-one in- or out-degree
      while(in-degree(e.target) == 1 && out-degree(e.target) == 1)
        e = e.target.out[0]
        path.push(e)

      #make a list of paths that reached the destination
      if(empty(destinations[e.target]))
        destinations[e.target] = []
      destinations[e.target].push(path)

    foreach(destinations as dest)
      if(dest.size > 1)
        allParallelPaths.push(dest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I understand your approach. I'll try to implement this and if it does what I am looking for, I'll mark your answer the solution.

Comment: @Kundor: sure, I know the drill. I'm not new to stack exchange but too new to stack overflow for my up vote to be seen. I appreciate the collaboration of you both a lot! Acceptance is on its way.

Comment: While this algorithm is a solution to my problem, I consider the solution given by @Kundor the better one.

Comment: @theej Kundor's is certainly cleaner, and avoids the assumptions. In some cases, this will be faster; as mentioned, his will potentially take O(2^n), whereas this is guaranteed to run in O(n^2). Keep it in mind if that takes too long.